# Python 3: Extraer coincidencias entre dos listas de tuplas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, comparaciones

Tengo dos listas de tuplas tal que:

```
lista1 = [(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)]
lista2 = [(d,2),(e,6),(f,1)]
```

Necesito sacar una lista con las coincidencias del segundo elemento que quede tal que así:

```
listaResultados = [(a,1,f),(b,2,d)]
```

Es decir, una lista de tuplas que incluya las coincidencias en formato "primer y segundo elemento de la coincidencia en lista1 + primer elemento de la coincidencia en lista2".

He visto que con `set(lista1).intersection(lista2)` se sacan las intersecciones, pero al ser lista de tuplas y buscar el segundo elemento me pierdo... ¿Sería más sencillo si en vez de lista de tuplas lo trabajo como lista de listas?

Comment: Hola tharok, una duda, ¿Puede haber elementos repetidos? ¿En una misma lista puede haber tuplas con el segundo elemento igual, `[(d, 1), (f, 1)]`? ¿Con el primer elemento igual `[[(d,2), (d, 1)]]`?¿Tuplas con los dos elementos iguales `[(d,2), (d,2)]`? Si algo de esto es posible, ¿qué resultado se busca?

Comment: Si, pueden darse los tres casos. Los que tendrían que valer para la lista resultante serían aquellos que coincidan el segundo elemento (los números en el ejemplo) y se añade a la tupla resultante las letras que acompañen al número en cada lista. Si la coincidencia se produce en la misma lista no se añade, tiene que haber coincidencia entre las dos listas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La posibilidad de repeticiones complica algo el tema, lo primero que se me ocurre es convertir las listas a diccionarios dónde la clave sea el segundo elemento y como valor un conjunto con todos aquellos primeros elementos que tengan el mismo segundo elemento. Hecho esto construir la lista de resultados no es mayor problema:

```
lista1 = [("a", 1),("b", 2),("c", 3)]
lista2 = [("d", 2),("e", 6),("f", 1)]

from collections import defaultdict

dict_1 = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in lista1:
    dict_1[b].add(a)

dict_2 = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in lista2:
    if b in dict_1:
        dict_2[b].add(a)

res = [(*dict_1[key], key, *dict_2[key]) for key in dict_2]
```

> ```
> >>> res
> [('b', 2, 'd'), ('a', 1, 'f')]
> ```

Las si hay tuplas completas repetidas en una misma lista se ignoran, si hay tuplas en las que solo un elemento está repetido:

```
# Primer elemento repetido en varias tuplas de la lista1
lista1 = [("a", 1),("a", 2),("c", 3)]
lista2 = [("d", 2),("e", 6),("f", 1)]  
res = [('a', 2, 'd'), ('a', 1, 'f')]

# Segundo elemento repetido en varias tuplas de la lista1
lista1 = [("a", 1),("b", 1),("c", 3)]
lista2 = [("d", 2),("e", 6),("f", 1)]
res = [('a', 'b', 1, 'f')]

# Primer elemento repetido en varias tuplas de la lista2
lista1 = [("a", 1),("b", 2),("c", 3)]
lista2 = [("d", 2),("e", 6),("f", 2)]
res = [('b', 2, 'd', 'f')]

# Segundo elemento repetido en varias tuplas de la lista2
lista1 = [("a", 1),("b", 2),("c", 3)]
lista2 = [("d", 1),("e", 6),("f", 1)]
res = [('a', 1, 'd', 'f')]
```